# Pi with C# instead of Python

Tags: gpio, pi-3, windows-iot, c#

I am very new to Pi but have a RPi 3 running windows 10 I.O.T. core. Can I do c# on it instead of Python? I am interested in some I.O.T. project using Pi but they use C instead of python which is more commonly used on the RPI. Just wondering this is possible with C# and RPi.

Comment: Why did it have raspbian **and** windows IOT core?

Comment: DO you want to use the GPIO? Well its better if you use WiringPi, which is a library for C/C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running Windows IoT core on the Pi.

You can use Visual Studio Community to develop in a range of languages for the Pi on IoT.

With C# you get the benefit of remote dubugging which is really usefull, and requires no setup (which is fantastic) - You do have a few flavours though, and Pi is slightly limited, in sense of multi app but fully capable of running a single app.

You have Console applications and UAP C#

I would suggest using UAP as it allows you to easily design slick GUI, and its universal so it will run on Windows 10 phones, Tablets and PC's too. (And Macintosh with Mono)

You should have a look on the Microsofts Official project gallery, for samples and ideas.

https://microsoft.hackster.io/en-US

Happy Codding.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you just need to install a compiler for it. One such compiler is called mono. [See here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=129710) how to install it (`mono-runtime`).

Comment: c# or Python which is easy and goes good with Pi

Comment: I've never touched C# myself, i'm a C/C++ guy and I've touched some Python. Python is probably easier to get into on a Pi, you have better support for stuff.

Comment: It's windows 10... Mono is for NON windows based OS's